# Trigger notification from report generation in R drake package

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I've set up a drake pipeline that generates a report at the end of the pipeline. I would like to trigger a slack notification every time a new report is created. For the report part of my plan I use the following:

```
report_plan <- drake::drake_plan(
  report = rmarkdown::render(
    knitr_in("alerts.Rmd"),
    output_file = file_out("report.html"),
    quiet = TRUE),
  notification = target(slackr::slackr("A new vaccine report is ready"),   trigger = trigger(change = file.info("report.html")$ctime)),
  strings_in_dots = "literals"
)
```

The trigger on the notification target works, but in my dependency graph the notification target is just hanging out by itself:

[image]

Is there a better way to make the notification dependent on a new report being generated? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's clever, I like it! What about a `file_in()` statement in the trigger? Maybe `trigger = trigger(change = file.info(file_in("report.html"))$ctime` If that triggers too often, maybe a `knitr_in()` statement on the source: `trigger = trigger(change = file.info(knitr_in("report.html"))$ctime`. I personally like the second of these options better.

Sorry I was so late in getting to this thread!

Comment: I noticed that even with the file_in() call  vis_drake_graph(drake_config(report_plan)) still shows a disconnected graph, but that bug is only in the visualization. plot(drake_config(report_plan)$graph) show that the notification actually does depend on the report when you use file_in("report.html") in the trigger.

Comment: Okay, in the GitHub development version (via https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commit/96d57fab0cfa4f9e99978d954298318e75bb5247) the graph visualization should show `"report.html"` as a dependency of `notification` if you use `file_in("report.html")`. But even before that patch to the visualization, your workflow should work as expected.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help on this! I'll check out the development version. Also thanks for such a cool package. I'm just getting going with it and look forward to using it more.